# SQL SELECT подзапросы

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]
Вывести название проекта, в котором заняты
сотрудники из максимального количества отделов.

```
SELECT PROJECT.Project
FROM PROJECT
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON PROJECT.ID_Project=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Project
INNER JOIN EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
INNER JOIN DEP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
```

Объединил только все необходимые таблицы для этого.
Тут нужно делать еще один подзапрос, только не знаю как.

Comment: Что значит "в котором заняты сотрудники из максимального количества отделов" ??? непонятное задание. Вам нужно название проекта в котором участвует максимальное количество отделов ?

Answer (score 3):

Надо сделать `GROUP BY` на таблицу Project, считать количество отделов в группе, сортировать по этому количеству, и вывести первый проект.

```
SELECT PROJECT.Project, COUNT(DEP.Department) AS DepartmentCount
FROM PROJECT
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON PROJECT.ID_Project=PROJECT_EMP.ID_Project
INNER JOIN EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
INNER JOIN DEP ON DEP.ID_Dep=EMP.ID_Dep
GROUP BY PROJECT.Project
ORDER BY DepartmentCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[Можно попробовать этот запрос на SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3213e/9)

Answer (score 1):

Проектов, удовлетворяющих этому условию может быть несколько. Следующий запрос выведет отсортированный по количеству участвующих отделов список проектов:

```sql
SELECT p.project, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id_dep) count_dep
FROM project p
JOIN project_emp pe ON pe.id_project = p.id_project
JOIN emp e ON e.id_emp = pe.id_emp
GROUP BY p.id_project
ORDER BY count_dep DESC
```

А дальше, если нужен только один из проектов, можно добавить `LIMIT 1`. Либо сделать подзапрос для извлечения только проектов с максимальным количеством отделов.